# Python dict converted to VB.net

Tags: python, vb.net, list, dictionary

I would like to find out if there is a way to easily convert a dictionary in Python to VB.net.
for example if I had a function that took a list and I want to make it when passing it in Python it would be:

```
function(['Hello', 'World!'])
```

If I wanted to do that in VB.net I would:

```
function({"Hello", "World"})
```

But I want to know if that is possible with dict's. Such as this in Python:

```
function({'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'})
```

If converting that to VB.net is not possible then is there a way I could pass a list of strings and convert it from a list to a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary and SortedDictionary are inbuilt types in the .NET Framework, so you should be fine.

This is C# - don't know VB:
Dictionary dct = new Dictionary() { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } };

That creates the dictionary and adds two members to it.

Cheers -